# Determine Taker Price from Bid/Ask Order Book

Tags: php, math, average

I am working on a bitcoin trading script in PHP. To run paper trading on live data, I have to determine buy/sell price from order book i.e taker price.

Order book live json data looks like [this](https://api.gdax.com/products/BTC-USD/book?level=2)

Order book has two main arrays - bids & asks. Each bid/ask array has price [0], quantity [1] and the third parameter [2] is irrelevant:

Bid/Ask Sample Array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8848.99
        [1] => 9.89850469
        [2] => 7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8848.2
        [1] => 0.05
        [2] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8848.02
        [1] => 0.274203
        [2] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8848.01
        [1] => 0.0012
        [2] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8847.47
        [1] => 0.5
        [2] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8846.99
        [1] => 0.28345
        [2] => 1
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8846.81
        [1] => 0.75
        [2] => 1
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8846
        [1] => 0.75181214
        [2] => 2
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8845.99
        [1] => 26.57694043
        [2] => 28
    )
```

From the above data, how to calculate average price for 15 or n number of coins in PHP? Considering that orders will be filled/taken from top to bottom as available.

Comment: Can you demonstrate any effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: does the `price` element represent the price of a single coin, or the total amount for this order?

Comment: It is price per coin and quantity is availability at that price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this Excel formula: 
`Avg. Cost = sumproduct(price series, qty series) / sum(qty series)`

Here is the PHP code:

```
$order_book = json_decode($order_book, true);
$bids = ($order_book['bids']);

$ordered = 15; //n number of coins
$filled = 0;
$fill_array = array();

foreach ($bids as $PriceQty) {

    $price = $PriceQty[0];
    $qty = $PriceQty[1];

    if ($ordered != $filled){

        $required = $ordered - $filled;

        if ($qty >= $required){
            $fill_array[] = array($price,$required);
            $filled = $filled + $required;
            break;
        }else{
            $filled = $filled + $qty;
            $fill_array[] = array($price,$qty);
        }   
    }   
}   

$totalQty = 0;
$totalSum = 0;

foreach ($fill_array as $PriceQty) {
    $totalSum = $totalSum + ($PriceQty[0] * $PriceQty[1]);
    $totalQty = $totalQty + $PriceQty[1];
}   

echo "$totalSum/$totalQty = ".($totalSum/$totalQty);
```

There might be simpler way of doing this, someone could improve this answer. For now it produces expected average.